# Cannot see application when logging into GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

We moved from an Exchange server to Google Apps and for shared contacts to work with Outlook, we installed Shared Groups on Google Apps Engine.

Before the actual move, the app was tested in trial mode with an administrator account. However, the person that set everything up deleted this account from the Google Apps domain because the company didn't think they would move to Google Apps until recently.

Now that the move has completed, I tried to install the Shared Groups application but it tells me this application is already installed for our domain.

So I recreated the exact account that the other person set up to install this application and logged into GAE but I cannot see it in the console. There's no application there.

Is there a way to have the application show up in the console because I can't edit the settings and enable billing. At the moment going to the application address returns "Error: Server Error".

Thank you.